# set Attr_accessor for all instance variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a 20 field database, and would like to set all the variables to be able to be accessed.

Is there a way to set attr_accessor to all of the variables, without listing each one i.e.

attr_accesor :a, :b, ... etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`attr_accessor` is for adding get/set methods on a plain ruby object. With an ActiveRecord model, these are created automatically based on the columns in your schema.

Normally all ActiveRecord attributes are "accessible" which means you can mass-assign values to all of them from the params hash: `Model.update_attributes(params[:model])`

You might be thinking of `attr_accessible` which makes only certain columns accessible this way, and makes the rest "protected", so they can only be assigned directly through their setter method.

The opposite is `attr_protected` which leaves all columns accessible except the ones you specify.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question (?), but if your model relates directly to the database, those properties are already accessible.

Comment: so then is attr_accessor really only used for instance variables that are not directly related to the database?